# How can I hide the path bar in the Mac Terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal

There's a bar under the title bar of the Mac terminal showing the path the terminal is open at. I'm pretty sure this has recently appeared and I'd like to removed it. Is there a way?

[image: Highlighted:]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is the tab bar (note the plus icon on the right to open a new tab).
As long as you only have one tab open in a Terminal window, you should be able to hide it by selecting "Hide Tab Bar" from the "View" menu.

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved. I must've hit that key combination which enabled it.

Comment: Happens to all of us. :)

Comment: Happened twice, even in some other Mac programs. Glad there's help out there on the net and such simple settings make me feel like I am a dumb guy though having used computers for 25 years :p